# c++: CGAL 2D delauny triangulation: Concave Shapes

Tags: triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I am currently getting into CGAL for some 2D triangulation tasks and I also got something simple to work allready. Anyhow I dont really get how to triangulate concave shapes since Right now I always get the convex hull of all points. Basically I want to add points on mouseClick similar to how it works in illustrator so that all the points in their order are the outline of the shape. How can I do that with CGAL? A simple example of how to triangulate concave shapes in general would propably put me onto the right track! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml

Comment: I think the problem is to triangulate concave polygons. The above link shows convex polygons triangulation. Also the programmer mentioned that above the code. If you have any algorithm that solves the triangulation of polygons that has holes like one more polygons please share. The problem submitter also requested for an algorithm of non-convex polygons

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll first need to [partition](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/last/doc_html/cgal_manual/Partition_2_ref/Function_greene_approx_convex_partition_2.html#Cross_link_anchor_997) the polygon into convex pieces. After this you can create triangles of each individual polygon with something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i + 1 < polygon.size(); ++i) {
    const Point_2& v0 = polygon[0];
    const Point_2& v1 = polygon[i];
    const Point_2& v2 = polygon[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: hey, I looked into that but could not really get it to work. shouldn't it be possible to create concave shapes with constrained_delauny triangulation? if so, does anyone have an example available?

Thanks!

Comment: Using delaunay triangulation for this seems like major overkill. Delaunay triangulation is most often used to triangulate ('mesh') a 2D area so that you can solve various partial differential equations on it using finite elements. In this scenario you also create a lot of extra vertices inside the area. In what way didn't the partition function work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a convex outline instead of concave, it's probably due to the alpha value passed in. Try using find_optimal_alpha(1) as the alpha value or calculate values relative to the bounding size of the point cloud you're passing in. eg.

```
Alpha_shape_2 aShape(inPoints.begin(), inPoints.end());
aShape.set_alpha( aShape.find_optimal_alpha(1) );
aShape.set_mode(Alpha_shape_2::REGULARIZED);
```